# Including three level dummy variables to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's consider panel data with 300 rows deleted

```
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
set.seed(42)
EmplUK<-EmplUK[-sample(1:nrow(EmplUK),300),]
  firm year sector    emp    wage capital   output
1    1 1977      7  5.041 13.1516  0.5894  95.7072
4    1 1980      7  4.715 13.8039  0.6171 100.5501
5    1 1981      7  4.093 14.2897  0.5076  99.5581
6    1 1982      7  3.166 14.8681  0.4229  98.6151
7    1 1983      7  2.936 13.7784  0.3920 100.0301
8    2 1977      7 71.319 14.7909 16.9363  95.7072
```

I want to add three level dummy variables with respect to years.(So I want to have three additional columns).

The problem is that each firm don't have same numbers of observed years i.e. firm one has 1977, 1980, 1981, 1982 So Dummy variables should be :

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

Firm three has 1977,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983. Dummies should looks following

```
1 0 0
0 1 0 
0 0 1
1 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1
```

I know that to create dummy variables we just need to use command :

```
model.matrix(~ factor(cycle(ts(EmplUK, frequency = 3)))+0)
```

but I have no idea how to divide this into the years. Do you have any ideas how it can be adjusted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a factor variable first by repeating `c(1,2,3)` for each firm. Then, use `model.matrix` to expand that into dummies.

```
EmplUK <- within(EmplUK, {
  dummy <- as.factor(ave(year, firm, FUN = function(x) rep_len(c(1L, 2L, 3L), length(x))))
})
cbind(EmplUK, model.matrix(~ dummy - 1, data = EmplUK))
```

The output looks like this

```
   firm year sector       emp    wage capital   output dummy dummy1 dummy2 dummy3
1     1 1977      7  5.041000 13.1516  0.5894  95.7072     1      1      0      0
2     1 1978      7  5.600000 12.3018  0.6318  97.3569     2      0      1      0
3     1 1979      7  5.015000 12.8395  0.6771  99.6083     3      0      0      1
4     1 1980      7  4.715000 13.8039  0.6171 100.5501     1      1      0      0
5     1 1981      7  4.093000 14.2897  0.5076  99.5581     2      0      1      0
6     1 1982      7  3.166000 14.8681  0.4229  98.6151     3      0      0      1
7     1 1983      7  2.936000 13.7784  0.3920 100.0301     1      1      0      0
8     2 1977      7 71.319000 14.7909 16.9363  95.7072     1      1      0      0
9     2 1978      7 70.642998 14.1036 17.2422  97.3569     2      0      1      0
10    2 1979      7 70.917999 14.9534 17.5413  99.6083     3      0      0      1
11    2 1980      7 72.030998 15.4910 17.6574 100.5501     1      1      0      0
12    2 1981      7 73.689003 16.1969 16.7133  99.5581     2      0      1      0
13    2 1982      7 72.418999 16.1314 16.2469  98.6151     3      0      0      1
14    2 1983      7 68.517998 16.3051 17.3696 100.0301     1      1      0      0
...
```